# How to turn off DocFX build each time i rebuild project in Visual Studio [2019] [NuGet]

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, docfx

I tried to start using DocFX and it meets my requirements, but I have a minor problem that is quite bothersome in the long run.

Every time I change something in the project and enable debugging, the DocFX's nuget adapts to the new changes.

This is correct behavior, but I would like to be able to turn this off for some time.
It doesn't take long, but due to frequent changes it significantly extends the time to test anything.

I was looking in user Manual:
https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx.exe_user_manual.html
and I tried to do it on my own, but I didn't find any way to do that except to throw the nuget out of the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to turn off DocFX build each time i rebuild project in Visual
>   Studio [2019] [NuGet]

This is the feature of the nuget package `docfx.console` and I suggest you could turn off this nuget package temporarily by this way:

Use a new configuration which removes the `docfx` nuget package to test it.

**1)** add a new configuration called test

[image]

**2)** If it is a net framework project with **packages.config**, you should

change this in `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\docfx.console.2.55.0\build\docfx.console.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\docfx.console.2.55.0\build\docfx.console.targets')/>
```

to

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\docfx.console.2.55.0\build\docfx.console.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\docfx.console.2.55.0\build\docfx.console.targets') and '$(Configuration)'!='Test'" />
```

**Then**, you can switch the configuration as you want to get your goal.

The **Test** Configuration will not consume the package and other configuration will consume it.

=========================

If it is a net project with **PackageReference**, you should add `<ExcludeAssets>buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets>` under **PackageReference** node to prevent consumption of the target files of the package：

Like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="docfx.console" >
            <Version>2.55.0</Version>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <ExcludeAssets>buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It worked! Adding <ExcludeAssets>buildtransitive</ExcludeAssets>  under PackageReference worked. But, changing Project from Debug to Test doesn't change *.csproject. Is it normal? I can add or remove that line manually, but your solution seems really good, want to try it.

Comment: `changing Project from Debug to Test ` will not make any changes to your project, just change your output path to the Test folder. It's just that you can switch the configuration to get what you want directly without having to delete or comment the line manually. If you directly comment, it is also feasible.

Comment: As far as I can tell, projects that use PackageReference cannot use the `$(Configuration)` condition [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition), so it's not possible to enable/disable building DocFX depending on the build target. Instead, go to Solution Explorer in VisualStudio, select the "docfx.console" package and add `buildtransitv` to the "Excluded assets" in the Properties.